# Get parameters information from a closure in runtime in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, runtime, closures

As you may know, there is no NSMethodSignature in Swift (more info e.g: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=19) Still, I would like to get in runtime information about the parameters in my closure. So if I had defined this closure:

```
 var theClosure: ((someString: String) -> ())?
```

I would like to know in runtime the parameter name ("someString") and the type (String). Is this still possible somehow? I could have as suggested a static table with that information, but i find it nicer to get the information in runtime. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's your use case?  You may well be able to achieve your goal using generics statically rather than using type information dynamically.

Comment: I would like to create functions in JavaScript with that signature, so I do have to write in code the parameters everytime I create a native object convertible to JS.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure about the parameter name, but for the type information there is the `dynamicType` property.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1137):

> [...] You can use a dynamicType expression with an instance of a type to access
>   that instance’s runtime type as a value [...]

Their example code for this is basically `let ourType = someInstance.dynamicType`. If you want that type as a string, you can use the `printClassName()` class method.